# Empty array from factory method in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework, factory

Scenario: I have a factory service that has the following code

```
appServices.factory('MyDB', function ($cordovaSQLite)
{      
var FixedCache = []; 

return {

    getFromCache: function (dataURL, $scope)
    {
        var query = "SELECT * FROM FixedCache WHERE URI_ID = '"+dataURL+"'";
        FixedCache = [];    
        $scope.dataFromCache = [];        

        //console.log("Inside Cache method");
        // Execute query statement from query variable.
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function (res)
        {                
            if (res.rows.length > 0)
            {


                        var dataItem = {
                            id          : res.rows.item(0).id           ,
                            URI_ID      : res.rows.item(0).URI_ID    ,
                            ExpireDate  : res.rows.item(0).ExpireDate     ,
                            JSONData    : res.rows.item(0).JSONData                            
                        };                            

                        FixedCache.push(dataItem);  
                        $scope.dataFromCache = FixedCache;                            


            }



        }); 

        return FixedCache;

    },// End select all data.        
};
```

})

In the controller, I want to get the data by calling this method. Here is the code of controller.

```
appControllers.controller('categoriesCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $state, $timeout, $stateParams, $ionicHistory, MyDB, UtilityMethods) {

var dataURL = window.globalVariable.constants.URL_API;

$scope.initialForm = function () {


    $scope.categoriesFromCache = [];
    $scope.categoryCache;


    $scope.url = window.globalVariable.constants.URL_API;
    $scope.todaysDate = UtilityMethods.GetDate(0);

    // $scope.isLoading is the variable use for loading.
    $scope.isLoading = false;           

    $scope.apiUrl = window.globalVariable.constants.URL_API;


};// End initialForm.


$scope.GetFromCache = function (uri, $scope) {


    $scope.dataFromCache = [];        

    MyDB.getFromCache(uri, $scope);              
};

$scope.navigateTo = function (targetPage, objectData, apiUrl) {

    $state.go(targetPage, {
        category: objectData,
        apiUrl: apiUrl
    });
};



$scope.clearSearch = function() {
    $scope.searchByName = '';
};


$scope.goBack = function () {
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
        disableBack: true
    });
    $state.go("app.categories", {
        isShowError: false
    });
};

$scope.initialForm();


   $timeout(function () {            
        $scope.GetFromCache(dataURL, $scope);


    }, 3000);// End loading progress.
```

});

Problem: 
When I am calling this method MyDB.getFromCache(uri, $scope);  in controller, it is returning empty array []
The database does contains the data.

Please guide me. Am I calling the functions correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind your code isn't working is, you are considering async event to work in synchronous way, though additional I want to say passing `$scope` as an parameter to factory method isn't considered as good practice.

Basically what you need to do is return cordova `promise` from method & chain that promise inside controller & set scope variable in it.

**Factory**

```
getFromCache: function(dataURL) {
  var query = "SELECT * FROM FixedCache WHERE URI_ID = '" + dataURL + "'";
  FixedCache = [];
  //returning cordova promise
  return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) {
    if (res.rows.length > 0) {
      var dataItem = {
        id: res.rows.item(0).id,
        URI_ID: res.rows.item(0).URI_ID,
        ExpireDate: res.rows.item(0).ExpireDate,
        JSONData: res.rows.item(0).JSONData
      };

      FixedCache.push(dataItem);
      return FixedCache; //return data to chained promise
    }
  });
}
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.GetFromCache(dataURL).then(function(data){                
     $scope.dataFromCache = data;
});
```

Comment: @Abubaker Glad to help you out, Thanks :-)

Comment: I really am glad I got the answer. I am a newbie in Angularjs. Still stuck with loader while the data is being pulled from factory :) Working on it.

Comment: What do you mean by loader here?

Comment: When the data is being loaded from DB it takes at least a second or so. Also when data is being get via http request, it takes a few seconds, so need to show a loader during the request.

Comment: I also have another question a bit off-topic. How do you guys get notified that a question is posted on Stack Overflow. I got your reply very fast.

Comment: From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) link we can see questions added for particular tag